# Can I search for commits in a range of tags in the GitHub gui?

Tags: github

On the git commandline, I can run:

***$ git log --oneline --decorate vtagint007..vtagint010***

to get a list of all commits in that range of tags.

This is fine for our engineers.

For management types however, they are not git users and require the ability to list commits falling between a range of release tags, using the gui, in the least gittish manner possible.

I do not see a way to do this using the search box (or any other query) in the GitHub gui.

Is a search like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them visit https://github.com/your-org/your-repo/compare (replace 'your-org' and 'your-repo'). Here's a screenshot from GitHub's Elixir repo.

[image: github elixir repo compare screen]

There you can compare any two branches, tags, commits, or markers.

Comment: OK, cool! That seems to be spot-on, as far as the type of information they would be looking to gather.

Thank you!